# how to disable ejb-timer if quartz is already in place?

Tags: timer, jboss, ejb, jbpm

We have enabled quartz timer service in our jBPM server. We have created a quartz datasource and updated the timer-service in standalone.xml like below

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="db-store">
    <data-stores>
        <database-data-store name="db-store" datasource-jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/quartzDS"/>
    </data-stores>
</timer-service>
```

But when we start server, we get an error from ejb-timer service
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "jboss_ejb_timer" does not exist
 Position: 463

Is there a way to diable ejb-timer service if we are already using quartz timer?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to disable the timer service.

Just leave the standard configuration in place.

However, if your code actually contains EJB timers then you should configure them properly. You cannot just arbitrarily elect to use Quartz as an EJB timer implementation - EJB timers and Quartz are completely independent of each other.